# multiple dynamic input onchange and onblur function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have multiple input that when you select the option, the stock and the price would come out on other input to be used for another function.
i've tried to add unique id's for the inputs added but i just cant seem to figure out how to apply the function to the added inputs.

here is the Html:

```
<div id="container1">
 <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <select class="form-control border-teal" id="produk_nama1" name="produk_nama[]">
            <option value="">Pilih Produk</option>
            @foreach ($stoks as $stok)
            <option data-stok="{{$stok->stok}}" data-price="{{$stok->harga}}" value="{{$stok->produk->produk}}">{{$stok->produk->produk}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <div class="d-block form-text">
            <span id="stok1" class="badge bg-orange"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" id="harga1" name="harga[]" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Harga Produk" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="number" id="jumlah1" name="jumlah[]" min="1" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Masukkan Jumlah">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <input type="text" id="subtotal1" name="subtotal" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Subtotal" readonly>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var add_button = $("#add_button");
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var select = document.getElementById("produk_nama");
    var i = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        i++;
        $("#container1")

        var html = '<div class="form-group row">';

        // select buah
        html += '<div class="col-lg-3">';
        html += '<select class="form-control border-teal" id="produk_nama'+i+'" name="produk_nama[]">';
        html += '<option value="">Pilih Produk</option>';
        html += '@foreach ($stoks as $stok)';
        html += '<option data-stok="{{$stok->stok}}" data-price="{{$stok->harga}}" value="{{$stok->produk->produk}}">{{$stok->produk->produk}}</option>';
        html += '@endforeach';
        html += '</select>';
        html += '<div class="d-block form-text">';
        html += '<span id="stok'+i+'" class="badge bg-orange"></span>';
        html += '</div></div>';

        html += '<div class="col-lg-3">';
        html += '<input type="text" id="harga'+i+'" name="harga[]" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Harga Produk" readonly>';
        html += '</div>';

        html += '<div class="col-lg-3">';
        html += '<input type="number" id="jumlah'+i+'" name="jumlah[]" min="1" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Masukkan Jumlah">';
        html += '</div>';

        html += '<div class="col-lg-3">';
        html += '<input type="text" id="subtotal'+i+'" name="subtotal" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Subtotal" readonly>';
        html += '</div>';

        html += '</div>';


        $(this).before(html);

        // clone entire div
        // $("#container1")
        // .append(
        // $("#container1")
        // .children(inputs)
        // .first()
        // .clone()
        // )
        
    });

    // main input function
    $('#produk_nama'+i).on('change', function(){
        alert(i);
        var hargaproduk = $('#produk_nama'+i+' option:selected').data('price');
        var stok = $('#produk_nama'+i+' option:selected').data('stok');
        $('#stok'+i).text('Stok '+stok);
        $('#harga'+i).val(hargaproduk);
    });

    document.getElementById('jumlah'+i).addEventListener("blur", function(){
        var jumlah = $('#jumlah'+i).val();
        var harga = $('#harga'+i).val();
        var subtotal = jumlah * harga;
        $('#subtotal'+i).val(subtotal);
    })
    
});
```

any help and explanation would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: Hi, you are already using some sort of javascript framework. I would recommend you try and implement your logic using that framework instead of mixing both another framework and jquery. It makes it very hard to follow, especially given you are also then trying to build html in juery which conforms to your framework. So it's likely the two are conflicting and hence your issue.

Comment: javascript framework do you mean that jquery ? another framework i think i use is laravel.
could you explain where did it conflict?

Comment: Ah, understood. So presumably laravel runs server-side, in which case you are building up the form group on the client side inside  $(add_button).click event handler. I would recommend you use jquery exclusively for the client side code. So where you use laravel syntax for e.g '@foreach ($stoks as $stok), all that should be replaced with jquery syntax instead cause this is processed client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your first select-box i.e :`produk_nama` is same for all divs you can use ***clone()*** method to get clone of that select instead of writing laravel code inside jquery code.

Then , you can use `$(document).on("change", "select[name*=produk_nama]"..` to capture all change event on select-box . Inside this you can use `.closest()` and `.find()` method to get required values from input you needed and add the value to required inputs.Same you can do for `jumlah` input .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var add_button = $("#add_button");
  var i = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    i++;
    $("#container1")
    //get first div > selct clone it
    var slects = $('.outer:first').find("select").clone();
    var html = '<div class="form-group row outer">';
    html += '<div class="col-lg-3">';
    html += '<select class="form-control border-teal" id="produk_nama' + i + '" name="produk_nama[]">';
    html += $(slects).html(); //add that 
    html += '</select>';
    html += '<div class="d-block form-text">';
    html += '<span id="stok' + i + '" class="badge bg-orange"></span>';
    html += '</div></div>';

    html += '<div class="col-lg-3">';
    html += '<input type="text" id="harga' + i + '" name="harga[]" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Harga Produk" readonly>';
    html += '</div>';

    html += '<div class="col-lg-3">';
    html += '<input type="number" id="jumlah' + i + '" name="jumlah[]" min="1" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Masukkan Jumlah">';
    html += '</div>';

    html += '<div class="col-lg-3">';
    html += '<input type="text" id="subtotal' + i + '" name="subtotal" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Subtotal" readonly>';
    html += '</div>';

    html += '</div>';


    $(this).before(html);

  });

  //on change of selct
  $(document).on("change", "select[name*=produk_nama]", function() {
    //get attrs values
    var hargaproduk = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-price');
    var stok = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-stok');
    //add the values to required elemnt
    $(this).closest(".outer").find(".d-block span").text('Stok ' + stok)
    $(this).closest(".outer").find("input[name*=harga]").val(hargaproduk);
  });

  $(document).on("blur", "input[name*=jumlah]", function() {
    var jumlah = $(this).val(); //get value
    var harga = $(this).closest(".outer").find("input[name*=harga]").val();
    var subtotal = jumlah * harga;
    //add value to subtotal 
$(this).closest(".outer").find("input[name=subtotal]").val(subtotal);
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container1">
<!--just added outer class-->
  <div class="form-group row outer">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <select class="form-control border-teal" id="produk_nama1" name="produk_nama[]">
        <option value="">Pilih Produk</option>

        <option data-stok="something" data-price="12" value="1">1</option>
        <option data-stok="something" data-price="13" value="2">2</option>
        <option data-stok="something" data-price="14" value="3">3</option>

      </select>
      <div class="d-block form-text">
        <span id="stok1" class="badge bg-orange"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input type="text" id="harga1" name="harga[]" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Harga Produk" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input type="number" id="jumlah1" name="jumlah[]" min="1" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Masukkan Jumlah">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input type="text" id="subtotal1" name="subtotal" class="form-control border-teal border-1" placeholder="Subtotal" readonly>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<button id="add_button">Add more</button>
```

Comment: some term that you wrote here are new to me. it'll take time to study the code and then apply that to mine. such as .outer, find, closest. what does .outer do? and thank you for answering!

Comment: .outer is just a class name..which I have added in your html structure ..check above html code :) and `:first` will get you first div with class name `outer`

Comment: oh i see, im so focused on reading the javascript that i thought .outer was a js function. sorry abt that. so by using clone(), i can avoid writing that foreach on javascript. i can guess what closest and find do, thats pretty handy! but what about the * do in : select[name*=produk_nama] ?

Comment: It means any letter after the `produk_nama` as you cannot use brackets in selectors it will give you error.. Also I would suggest you go through the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) for understanding better :)